# YARN: Slave DataNode not doing work despite looking up and healthy

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a two node Haoop 2.7.1 installation on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. All the demons are up and running after `sbin/start-dfs.sh && sbin/start-yarn.sh` as confirmed by `jps`.

However, only the Master node(it doubles as slave) is doing work while the slave-node's DataNode sits idle.

The weird thing is that the `tmp` folder of the slave-node is being populated by `nm-local-dir` (created by the ResourceManager I presume).

All configuration seems fine and I have tried every trick that the Internet can suggest- but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the local datanode/namenode folder on the master node and all the slave nodes then do `hdfs namenode -format` 
I think that the problem is an inconsistency in the clusterID between the master and the slaves.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that a lot of times (before posting the question). Nothing there!

Comment: You can check the ClusterID manually, Just to make sure.  hdfs/namenode/current/VERSION it should contain the same clusterID of all the slaves in hdfs/datanode/current/VERSION

Comment: The two files contain the same VERSION numbers. hdfs/namenode/ and hdfs/datanode on the slave node stays empty, though. Only the master node's hdfs/namenode and hdfs/datanode files are being populated by current folder.

Comment: @Reda that means the Slaves are not set properly inside the master node, so when you do format to the master node the slaves does not get updated. Check the slaves file inside your configurations folder. make sure it contains correct information for the slave nodes.

Comment: Thanks @Abdulrahman. I have checked the slaves file and it is correct. I mean, the tmp file in hdfs/tmp wouldn't have been populated had that info was not correct after-all. I have now removed the master node from the slaves list so as to see what the logs would look like. It seems that the problem is similar to this link https://cloudcelebrity.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/hadoop-hdfs-error-xxxx-could-only-be-replicated-to-0-nodes-instead-of-1/  But the solution proposed there did nothing in my case.